# Using loaders to display data from SQLlite in listview in fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, loader, asynctaskloader

My app implementation is an activity which uses Viewpager and different fragments to show on screen depending on tab selection or user swiping the screen. I have attached the screenshot example.[image]

Now I want to load data on these fragments from my database in a listview. I was reading about loaders but not sure how to implement - whether to use Cursorloader which uses content provider or to use Asynctaskloader. I want to avoid Cursorloader since it mandates uses of content provider, however let me know if it will still make sense to go for it rather than Asynctaskloader.
Also, can I use a single loader maybe in activity and use this loader to display data in different fragments? Or should I be implementing a loader for each of the fragments?
Before thinking to use loaders I previously had used Simplecursoradapter to display the results but I have heard its better to use loaders for asynchronous operations. But let me know if Simplecursoradapter will suffice for lightweight operation.

I know I have asked too many questions but I am a beginner and a little confused at this point. Please help.